# Replacing Column Value When Another Column Value Changes

Tags: r, dataframe

In below data, I want to keep track of `U` and `Value` column. As soon as value of column `Value` changes for the rows having same value at `U` column, I want to assign `U` column with `NA`.

Any suggestions on how to approach this efficiently?

**Input Data**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
U   Value   Debug
A   1     1231
A   1     41
A   2     -1149
A   2     -2339
B   3     -3529
B   4     -4719
C   5     -5909
C   5     -7099
C   5     -8289
C   6     -9479
C   6     -10669
C   6     -11859
D   7     -13049
D   7     -14239
D   8     -15429
D   8     -16619")
```

**Current Table Output**

```
U   Value   Debug
A   1   1231
A   1   41
A   2   -1149
A   2   -2339
B   3   -3529
B   4   -4719
C   5   -5909
C   5   -7099
C   5   -8289
C   6   -9479
C   6   -10669
C   6   -11859
D   7   -13049
D   7   -14239
D   8   -15429
D   8   -16619
```

**Expected Table Output**

```
U   Value   Debug
A   1   1231
A   1   41
NA  2   -1149
NA  2   -2339
B   3   -3529
NA  4   -4719
C   5   -5909
C   5   -7099
C   5   -8289
NA  6   -9479
NA  6   -10669
NA  6   -11859
D   7   -13049
D   7   -14239
NA  8   -15429
NA  8   -16619
```

Comment: I don't understand why there are several groups of multiple `NA`.  It would seem to me that only the first `U` value in a group would be assigned to `NA`.  Can you explain your output?

Comment: .@TimBiegeleisen - Yes. Consider first four rows of `Current Table Output`. They all have same value for column `U`. I want to assign `NA` to all rows after the first change of value in column `Value`. Same operation then will be applied to next sub set of data having column values as `B` and then `C` and then `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(data)`), grouped by `U`, get the run-length-id of `Value` column (based on the change of values, the `rleid` - increments value), convert it to a binary with mod operator (`%%`), which is converted to logical by negating (`!`) so that 0's become `TRUE` and 1's `FALSE`, get the row index of `TRUE` values (`.I`), extract that column (`$V1`) and use that as `i` to assign (`:=`) values of `U` to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data[, .I[!rleid(Value) %%2], U]$V1, U := NA]
data
#       U Value  Debug
# 1:    A     1   1231
# 2:    A     1     41
# 3: <NA>     2  -1149
# 4: <NA>     2  -2339
# 5:    B     3  -3529
# 6: <NA>     4  -4719
# 7:    C     5  -5909
# 8:    C     5  -7099
# 9:    C     5  -8289
#10: <NA>     6  -9479
#11: <NA>     6 -10669
#12: <NA>     6 -11859
#13:    D     7 -13049
#14:    D     7 -14239
#15: <NA>     8 -15429
#16: <NA>     8 -16619
```

#### Update

Based on the discussion with OP, we need to assign NA 'U' where the 'Value' is not the `first` 'Value' for each 'U'

```
setDT(data)[data[,  .I[Value != first(Value)], .(U)]$V1, U := NA]
```

or the same logic in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(U1 = U) %>%
   mutate(U = replace(U, Value != first(Value), NA)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-U1)
```

Comment: .@akrun - Thank you. What's `V1`? Can I use your solution if `Value` column is non-numeric?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Yes, you can use for non-numeric as well, `rleid` gets the run-length-id based on changes in adjacent element.  Here, V1 is the default column output of `.I` i.e. index extracted

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  You can check the output of `rleid(c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A"))`

Comment: .@akrun - In the big data I have, it's only replacing the first change and then keeps the rest rows for same `U` values as it's. Any guess why this is the case? The data is too big to share.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil if the data pattern is similar to the one you mentioned, it should work `v1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B");!rleid(v1) %% 2#
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`, If you check here, it is not only the first change, that is getting TRUE

Comment: .@akrun - Sorry, it's not the first change. It's actually taking set of two for sub set of data frame where `U` is same and then only assigning `NA` to the second one. To replicate my output on above data it's changing row 2 `U` value to `NA` and then changing row r `U` value to `NA` and so on.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Sorry, it is not clear from the comments.  Can you update your example with a new one and expected output

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Here, it is changing exactly like that because the values are not changing for the first two rows it is 1, then on 3rd, it changes to 2,

Comment: .@akrun - Agree with your answer for the above sample data. For my case let's say if the number of rows for which `U` has value `A` is `16`, then it's dividing it into set of two and the changing the `U` value to `NA` for even number of rows only.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Please update with a new example/expected output so that it can be easier to understand.  here, we are doing the mod of the `id`s created with `rleid` and not on the actual values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190817/discussion-between-chetan-arvind-patil-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
data %>%
    group_by(U) %>%
    mutate(
        grp = cumsum(!(lag(Value, default = F) == Value)),
        U.new = ifelse(grp == 1, as.character(U), NA))
## A tibble: 16 x 5
## Groups:   U [4]
#   U     Value  Debug   grp U.new
#   <fct> <int>  <int> <int> <chr>
# 1 A         1   1231     1 A
# 2 A         1     41     1 A
# 3 A         2  -1149     2 NA
# 4 A         2  -2339     2 NA
# 5 B         3  -3529     1 B
# 6 B         4  -4719     2 NA
# 7 C         5  -5909     1 C
# 8 C         5  -7099     1 C
# 9 C         5  -8289     1 C
#10 C         6  -9479     2 NA
#11 C         6 -10669     2 NA
#12 C         6 -11859     2 NA
#13 D         7 -13049     1 D
#14 D         7 -14239     1 D
#15 D         8 -15429     2 NA
#16 D         8 -16619     2 NA
```

I'm creating a new column `U.new` here, as we're grouping by `U`.

---

In response to your comment, to replace `U` with `U.new` you can do

```
data %>%
    group_by(U) %>%
    mutate(
        grp = cumsum(!(lag(Value, default = F) == Value)),
        U.new = if_else(grp == 1, as.character(U), "NA")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(U = U.new, Value, Debug)
## A tibble: 16 x 3
#   U     Value  Debug
#   <chr> <int>  <int>
# 1 A         1   1231
# 2 A         1     41
# 3 NA        2  -1149
# 4 NA        2  -2339
# 5 B         3  -3529
# 6 NA        4  -4719
# 7 C         5  -5909
# 8 C         5  -7099
# 9 C         5  -8289
#10 NA        6  -9479
#11 NA        6 -10669
#12 NA        6 -11859
#13 D         7 -13049
#14 D         7 -14239
#15 NA        8 -15429
#16 NA        8 -16619
```

Comment: .@MauritsEvers - Thank you. Is it not possible to simply update the same data frame?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil No I don't think that's possible directly, because you're grouping by `U`. You could add a few extra steps to (1) `ungroup`, (2) replace `U` with `U.new` and (3) remove `U.new`. See my updated answer.

Comment: .@MauritsEvers - The big data I have has column name like `Data-1` for column `U`. I tried this `Data-1.new`, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to handle such column name for your code?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil That's a pretty bad (un-R-like) column name. But this will still work if you use backticks when you create the new column.

Comment: .@MauritsEvers - Noted, will improve. If column `Value` is non-numeric, will your code work?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil you keep changing parameters of your question which is not very helpful nor polite to those who are putting in effort towards answering your question. In response to your comment: yes this will work for non numeric `Value`. You can try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `dplyr` is for each group (`U`) find the first row where `Value` is different from the previous one and change those rows to `NA` thereafter.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(U) %>%
  mutate(U1 = replace(U, row_number() > which.max(diff(Value) != 0), NA))

#   U     Value  Debug U1   
#   <fct> <int>  <int> <fct>
# 1 A         1   1231 A    
# 2 A         1     41 A    
# 3 A         2  -1149 NA   
# 4 A         2  -2339 NA   
# 5 B         3  -3529 B    
# 6 B         4  -4719 NA   
# 7 C         5  -5909 C    
# 8 C         5  -7099 C    
# 9 C         5  -8289 C    
#10 C         6  -9479 NA   
#11 C         6 -10669 NA   
#12 C         6 -11859 NA   
#13 D         7 -13049 D    
#14 D         7 -14239 D    
#15 D         8 -15429 NA   
#16 D         8 -16619 NA
```

If there could be non-numeric values in `Value` column we can use `lag` instead of `diff`

```
data %>%
  group_by(U) %>%
  mutate(U1 = replace(U, row_number() >= which.max(Value != lag(Value)), NA))
```